# Insert/Query Varchar(max) fields SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2016

I have several thousands of reports that mostly exceed 8000 characters. I have a table setup which is 3 shorter fields (varchar(7), nchar(9), varchar(4) and one called report (varchar(max)). Via the following powershell I load the reports into SQL Server 2016:

```
function load_data {
Param (
    [String]$SourceDir,
    [String]$Table
)

Get-Childitem $SourceDir | % {
    $name = $_.BaseName.Split('_')
    $content = (Get-Content $_.FullName)
    $sqlcontent = ""
    $content | % {
        $sline = $_.replace("'", "''")
        # the line below=wrong and should contain the cast see update below
        $line = "'" + $sline + "'+CHAR(10)+"
        $sqlcontent = $sqlContent + $line
    }    
    $sqlcontent = $sqlcontent.Trim('+')
    # Insert in SQL
    $sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO $Table VALUES("
    $sqlcommand += "'" + $name[1].TrimStart('0') + "',"
    $sqlcommand += "'" + $name[0] + "',"
    $sqlcommand += "'" + $name[2] + "',"
    $sqlcommand += "CAST(" + $sqlcontent + " AS nvarchar(MAX))"
    $sqlcommand += ")"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlcommand -ServerInstance $sqlServerInstance -Database $sqlDatabase -OutputSqlErrors $true                
}
 }
 load_data $dir $table
```

The above runs without errors (so no truncating errors).

Now I'm not sure that anything beyond 8000 chars is loaded via the above. When I query SQL `select *, len(report) from TABLE where len(report) > 7999` I only seem to get 8000 characters returned. When I copy and paste the content from SQL Server Manager I only get the first 8000 characters.

(In the end a ASP.Net Entity Framework web app should pick it up and display the report).

So I am not sure if either I am inserting it wrong or if the query is wrong.

**UPDATED** : I fixed it :) in the above PowerShell the Cast is done around the complete $sqlcontent, but the cast should have been around each and every $_ in the concatenation, now it produces the correct result.

Comment: Did you try printing $sqlcontent to output, and see how many characters are displayed?

Comment: yes. e.g. current for first one: 10.521 chars

Comment: what is output of len(report) ?

Comment: len(report) in sql is 8000

Comment: I tried this on SQL 2012 and it was successful for me.  Using your script above, I created a file with 43K characters, the length of the string before the insert was 43K, and the length of the column after the insert was 43k.

Comment: I fixed it: the CAST was around the complete string, but should have been around the seperate parts in the concatenation, then it worked.